# Html.fromHtml() is deprecated, what is the alternative?

Tags: android, textview

I updated to the SDK Version 24 and now `Html.fromHtml()` is deprecated. And the Html class has a a new method with extra parameter named flag, but it's minimum API is 24.

Is there any alternative to this function to the lower API versions?. I don't want to use a `WebView` for this purpose.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Either:

- Use `Html.fromHtml(String)` on all API levels, or,
- Use `Html.fromHtml(String)` on API Level 23 and older devices, and `Html.fromHtml(String, int)` on API Level 24+ devices, using `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` to find out the API level of the device that you are running on

In this case, "deprecated" is a hint to go look for the two-parameter method, but the one-parameter method still works and (in all likelihood) will do so for quite some time.

Comment: on API Level 24+ Html.fromHtml(string,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);

Comment: Hello @CommonsWare, can we use HtmlEscapers class for this ?

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/guava/+/3ecfa41/guava/src/com/google/common/html/HtmlEscapers.java

Comment: @m0rpheu5: That doesn't seem to be a replacement for `Html`.

Comment: You can check what these flags do in this blog post: https://medium.com/@yair.kukielka/html-tags-in-android-nougat-textview-9f3554d7b705#.va79fruvy

Comment: `"FIELD HARDNESS <mark style=\"font-weight:600;color:#000;\">test</mark> REPORT"` is not working in this case. @CommonsWare

Comment: @Aks4125: `<mark>` is not an HTML tag understood by `Html`, most likely.

Comment: `HtmlCompat.fromHtml("<b>HTML</b>", HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)` is short and effective :D

Answer (score 58):

Just use

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
     Html.fromHtml(String, int) // for 24 api and more
 } else {
     Html.fromHtml(String) // or for older api
 }
```

to use Html.fromHtml(String, int) for 24 api follow documentation:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html

Comment: A small preference of mine:

 `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
     Html.fromHtml(String, int) // for 24 api and more
 } else {
     Html.fromHtml(String) // or for older api
 }`

Answer (score 12):

Actually there is another method with flag parameter

```
/** @deprecated */
@Deprecated
public static Spanned fromHtml(String source) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public static Spanned fromHtml(String source, int flags) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}
```

just use fromHtml function with flag parameter. flag parameters are

```
public static final int FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT = 63;
public static final int FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY = 0;
public static final int FROM_HTML_OPTION_USE_CSS_COLORS = 256;
public static final int FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_BLOCKQUOTE = 32;
public static final int FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_DIV = 16;
public static final int FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_HEADING = 2;
public static final int FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_LIST = 8;
public static final int FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_LIST_ITEM = 4;
public static final int FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_PARAGRAPH = 1;
public static final int TO_HTML_PARAGRAPH_LINES_CONSECUTIVE = 0;
public static final int TO_HTML_PARAGRAPH_LINES_INDIVIDUAL = 1;
```

Comment: That method call requires API 24 above, I found that and edited my question too,

Comment: @OmerKarakose the compiler cannot resolve the integer flag. It is expecting this format: fromHtml (String source, 
                int flags, 
                Html.ImageGetter imageGetter, 
                Html.TagHandler tagHandler)

Comment: @OmerKarakose  error: no suitable method found for fromHtml(String,int)
            urlBuilder.setText(Html.fromHtml(encodedUrl1, FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
                                   ^
    method Html.fromHtml(String) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Html.fromHtml(String,ImageGetter,TagHandler) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
1 error

Comment: @Anon I think you are not using android api level 24 or above. `Html.fromHtml(String source, int flags)` method is coming with **api 24**.

Comment: @OmerKarakose My target api in app:build.gradle is 23 Is that the problem?

Comment: @Anon yes that is the problem. if you want to build your application with newer api levels, you can upgrade from 23 to 25 for now. and if you do that upgrade, you will see `Html.fromHtml(String source)` function is deprecated. if you will stay at api level 23 or below, you can continue to use `Html.fromHtml(String source)` function.