# How to change text color of specific text in textview at runtime?

Tags: android, textview

I am getting multiple paragraph from server in the form of json object like

> MY name is <(>Mohit Kumar<)>. <(>Sachin<)> is my role model. I am
>   <(>12<)> year old. Currently i am in <(>delhi<)> but my hometown is
>   <(>bangalore<)>.

Now I want to remove start tag <(> and end tag <)> and change color of text which is inside those tags in android studio.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should provide the code you have tried and organize better your question, then we can help you in a better way.

Comment: @Sagar Aghara when you edit a question please concern about the content before you make suggestions.You tried to remove his requirement

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the user guidelines on how to ask a good question before posting a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you get a string like you mentioned,

If you want to color a text you can use `<font color='#EE0000'>TextYouWantToColor</font>` so you need to replace **<(>** with `<font color='#EE0000'>` and **<)>** with `</font>`

**Example**

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

  private  String yourString ;
  private  String yourNewString ;
  private  TextView tv ;
  private  String colorCodeStart = "<font color='#EE0000'>";  // use any color as  your want
  private  String colorCodeEnd = "</font>";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

        yourString = "MY name is <(>Mohit Kumar<)>. <(>Sachin<)> is my role model. I am <(>12<)> year old. Currently i am in <(>delhi<)> but my hometown is <(>bangalore<)>.";
        yourNewString =  yourString.replace("<(>",colorCodeStart); // <(> and <)> are different replace them with your color code String, First one with start tag
        yourNewString=  yourNewString.replace("<)>",colorCodeEnd); // then end tag
        Log.d("CheckNew",yourNewString);
        tv.setText((Html.fromHtml(yourNewString))); 

    }


}
```

**Note** :`Html.fromHtml()` is deprecated, what is the alternative? Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37899856/html-fromhtml-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replace tags with blank character, like

```
String s = new String("<(>Change me<)>");
        s=s.replace("<(>","");
        s=s.replace("<)>","");
```

then, to change TextColor of specific text, use SpannableString

```
SpannableString string = new SpannableString("Your string");
        string.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 1, 4, 0);
        string.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 5,string.length(), 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using a TextView, use this to change the color:

```
myTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: That will color all the text