# Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable' Unicode issue?

Tags: java, android, string, unicode, rippledrawable

Simply adding 🌑 (& #127761;) symbol as `android:text="&#127761; crash here"` to a TextView leads to app crash on following devices:

- Samsung Galaxy Star Plus (android 4.1.2)
- Lenovo S930 (android 4.4.2)
- LG Spirit LG-H422 (android 5.0.1)

Checked on an empty project created from scratch. LogCat output:

```
01-29 13:07:38.009 5780-5780/c7j.net.myapplication E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
01-29 13:07:38.094 5780-5780/c7j.net.myapplication E/dalvikvm: VM aborting
01-29 13:07:38.095 5780-5780/c7j.net.myapplication A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00001694 (code=-6), thread 5780 (t.myapplication)
01-29 13:07:38.096 5780-5780/c7j.net.myapplication A/libc: Send stop signal to pid:5780 in void debuggerd_signal_handler(int, siginfo_t*, void*)
```

**However, on Sony XA and Sony Z2 Tablet (Android 6.0.0) everything is fine, Unicode symbol displays as it should.**

**Question is:** Is this just not supported on pre-android 6.0 devices or by some manufacturers? And why do I see a ripple-drawable mentioned in Log-cat?

**EDIT:**
Finally the answer is a bug in NDK. Check @Charuka answer for details and workaround.

Comment: app did not crash with this text in textview on device Motorola E3 Power XT1706

Comment: @careful7j change the line from android:text="&#127761; crash here" to android:text="your name". Let me know if it is chrashing still?

Comment: @careful7j so you are saying you have not used any ripple on the view but this unicode pulls an error.Hmm Is that the full log?

Comment: Nope my app is not crashing if I remove this. Looks like we have a good answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The Java client passes a string containing a supplementary Unicode
   character to JNI/NDK.
2. JNI uses the NDK function GetStringUTFChars() to extract the contents of the Java string.
3. GetStringUTFChars() returns the string data as incorrect and invalid UTF-8.
4. Leads to a crash

Well that's kind of a [known bug](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2012-June/010403.html) seems a similer thing goes here!

You have given very small description,

> android:text="&#127761

Seems like you are trying to add the Unicode from your view.Normally you  should an error there saying

*unescaped & or non terminated character/entity reference*!

This way will work with the right Unicode!

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("&#127761"));
```

<sub>Hey Html.fromHtml() is deprecated? Yes see [what is the alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37899856/html-fromhtml-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative)!</sub>

---

**Edit** : Since your data is not enough I recreated the crash by myself using XML View(made sure only to use your view with that Unicode!). It crashed Nicely!

Here is the full log and error says all :

**JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal start byte 0xf0  ..illegal start byte in call to NewStringUTF** 
Well that's the error you are looking for!

This confirms what I said.

**Additionally**

This is your character > https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F311 called New Moon Symbol.
Those Unicodes used for system  emojis as well. So depending on the platform it may appear slightly different!

eg : in Samsung Galaxy S5

[image]

<sub>Source : http://emojipedia.org/samsung/galaxy-s5/new-moon-symbol/</sub>

**More**

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal start byte 0xf0
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     string: ''
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     in call to NewStringUTF
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     from java.lang.String android.content.res.StringBlock.nativeGetString(long, int)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x75748000 self=0xb4827800
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | sysTid=14933 nice=-11 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6f5abec
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=12 stm=4 core=1 HZ=100
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | stack=0xbe4b4000-0xbe4b6000 stackSize=8MB
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #00 pc 00004dfc  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (_ZN13UnwindCurrent6UnwindEjP8ucontext+23)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #01 pc 00003631  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (_ZN9Backtrace6UnwindEjP8ucontext+8)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #02 pc 00256a39  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiPKcPNS_6mirror9ArtMethodE+68)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #03 pc 0023a93d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+148)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #04 pc 000b5d07  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL8JniAbortEPKcS1_+582)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #05 pc 000b6437  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JniAbortFEPKcS1_z+58)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #06 pc 000b8839  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck5CheckEbPKcz.constprop.129+876)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #07 pc 000c10b9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI12NewStringUTFEP7_JNIEnvPKc+36)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #08 pc 00090c5b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #09 pc 0026e053  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (Java_android_content_res_StringBlock_nativeGetString__JI+102)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.content.res.StringBlock.nativeGetString(Native method)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:82)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   - locked <0x2b2c6a62> (a android.content.res.StringBlock)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getPooledString(XmlBlock.java:482)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:1003)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getText(TypedArray.java:145)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:991)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:685)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:681)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance!(Native method)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   - locked <0x141f57f3> (a java.lang.Object[])
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:436)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2245)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at user.example.charu.its2017huree.homeActivity.onCreate(homeActivity.java:26)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
02-01 07:34:43.382 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] 
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293] Runtime aborting...
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293] Aborting thread:
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293] "main" prio=10 tid=1 Native
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x75748000 self=0xb4827800
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   | sysTid=14933 nice=-11 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6f5abec
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=16 stm=6 core=1 HZ=100
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   | stack=0xbe4b4000-0xbe4b6000 stackSize=8MB
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   native: #00 pc 00004dfc  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (_ZN13UnwindCurrent6UnwindEjP8ucontext+23)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   native: #01 pc 00003631  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (_ZN9Backtrace6UnwindEjP8ucontext+8)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   native: #02 pc 00256a39  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiPKcPNS_6mirror9ArtMethodE+68)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   native: #03 pc 0023a93d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+148)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   native: #04 pc 0022a937  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10AbortState10DumpThreadERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEPNS_6ThreadE+22)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   native: #05 pc 0022abb3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10AbortState4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+386)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   native: #06 pc 0022ad61  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+72)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   native: #07 pc 000ac1c5  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD1Ev+1312)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   native: #08 pc 000b5eed  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL8JniAbortEPKcS1_+1068)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   native: #09 pc 000b6437  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JniAbortFEPKcS1_z+58)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   native: #10 pc 000b8839  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck5CheckEbPKcz.constprop.129+876)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   native: #11 pc 000c10b9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI12NewStringUTFEP7_JNIEnvPKc+36)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   native: #12 pc 00090c5b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   native: #13 pc 0026e053  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (Java_android_content_res_StringBlock_nativeGetString__JI+102)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.content.res.StringBlock.nativeGetString(Native method)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:82)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   - locked <0x2b2c6a62> (a android.content.res.StringBlock)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getPooledString(XmlBlock.java:482)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:1003)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getText(TypedArray.java:145)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:991)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:685)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:681)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance!(Native method)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   - locked <0x141f57f3> (a java.lang.Object[])
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:436)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2245)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at user.example.charu.its2017huree.homeActivity.onCreate(homeActivity.java:26)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293] Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock mutator lock
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293] All threads:
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293] DALVIK THREADS (11):
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293] "main" prio=10 tid=1 Native
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x75748000 self=0xb4827800
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   | sysTid=14933 nice=-11 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6f5abec
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=21 stm=6 core=1 HZ=100
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   | stack=0xbe4b4000-0xbe4b6000 stackSize=8MB
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   | held mutexes= "abort lock"
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   native: #00 pc 00004dfc  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (_ZN13UnwindCurrent6UnwindEjP8ucontext+23)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   native: #01 pc 00003631  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (_ZN9Backtrace6UnwindEjP8ucontext+8)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   native: #02 pc 00256a39  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiPKcPNS_6mirror9ArtMethodE+68)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   native: #03 pc 0023a93d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+148)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   native: #04 pc 00243a49  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList10DumpLockedERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+104)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   native: #05 pc 0022ab1f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10AbortState4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+238)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   native: #06 pc 0022ad61  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+72)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   native: #07 pc 000ac1c5  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD1Ev+1312)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   native: #08 pc 000b5eed  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL8JniAbortEPKcS1_+1068)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   native: #09 pc 000b6437  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JniAbortFEPKcS1_z+58)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   native: #10 pc 000b8839  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck5CheckEbPKcz.constprop.129+876)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   native: #11 pc 000c10b9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI12NewStringUTFEP7_JNIEnvPKc+36)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   native: #12 pc 00090c5b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   native: #13 pc 0026e053  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (Java_android_content_res_StringBlock_nativeGetString__JI+102)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.content.res.StringBlock.nativeGetString(Native method)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:82)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   - locked <0x2b2c6a62> (a android.content.res.StringBlock)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getPooledString(XmlBlock.java:482)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:1003)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getText(TypedArray.java:145)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:991)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:685)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:681)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance!(Native method)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   - locked <0x141f57f3> (a java.lang.Object[])
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:436)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2245)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at user.example.charu.its2017huree.homeActivity.onCreate(homeActivity.java:26)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
02-01 07:34:43.652 14933-14933/? A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:293]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Comment: Yes, looks like it explains many things. I have tried not coding it as string resource but use textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("&#127761")); and now it works.

Comment: But it's black-white now, while it was a colorful image on Android 6.0+ devices when was string resource. So mayby this is the reason also?

Comment: @careful7j lol i was here at the minute you post your comment but didn't notice that,mm didnt get that notification i followed the error and it led me to this interesting post --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127817/android-ics-4-0-ndk-newstringutf-is-crashing-down-the-app

Comment: @careful7j well i ll try to figure that out! I dont have lower api ones mm where is mu emulator bah :)

Comment: @careful7j updated my answer It seems we cannot help on that have a look

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer, now anyone who comes here will know about how does it works and what is going on.

Comment: also check this question from your pc and also from amobile phone.check the icon in your question.you will have a great chance to notice the difference!

Answer (score 0):

Android has a a xml a tribute for this in xml do
Android:background="?attr/selectablebackground"
Has a ripple effect that might be what your after?

Comment: Nope, my simple textView has no selectable background or ripple effects attached - it's not an imageview after all. Or mayby there is something that I don't know.

Comment: hang on let me look through my code... there is a google material design support button that is a Text button that wasnt to hard to configure.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what are you talking about. You don't need a button to catch this issue - only a plain textView

Answer (score 0):

Try this define `&#127761` in string.

```
<string name="unicode_str">&#127761;</string>
```

and on the textview

```
android:text = "@string/unicode_str"
```

Comment: Yeap, I did it like that in my application. Here in example I put it like that just to reduce the number of text since the result is equal anyways :)